# mojolicious routes not working

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am going over the documentation
http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite

I'm pasting the examples in the tutorial and I get this error message almost always:

Page not found... yet!

the last example i tried was this:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

  get '/with_layout';

  app->start;
  __DATA__

  @@ with_layout.html.ep
  % title 'Green';
  % layout 'green';
  Hello World!

  @@ layouts/green.html.ep
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head><title><%= title %></title></head>
    <body><%= content %></body>
  </html>
```

this is the error I get

```
[Thu Nov 14 03:43:15 2013] [debug] GET "/with_layout".
[Thu Nov 14 03:43:15 2013] [debug] Template "with_layout.html.ep" not found.
[Thu Nov 14 03:43:15 2013] [debug] Template "not_found.development.html.ep" not found.
[Thu Nov 14 03:43:15 2013] [debug] Template "not_found.html.ep" not found.
[Thu Nov 14 03:43:15 2013] [debug] Rendering cached inline template.
[Thu Nov 14 03:43:15 2013] [debug] Rendering cached inline template.
[Thu Nov 14 03:43:15 2013] [debug] 404 Not Found (0.011649s, 85.844/s).
```

Comment: nevermind it was the indentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you missing the subroutine to define the route?!

from the [docs](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite) you can get this:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

# Route leading to an action that renders a template
get '/with_layout' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render('foo');
};

app->start;
__DATA__

@@ with_layout.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title><%= title %></title></head>
  <body><%= content %></body>
</html>
```

better is this:

```
get '/with_layout' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render(template => 'with_layout', format => 'html', handler => 'ep');
    return;
};
```

now the errors:

```
Template "not_found.development.html.ep" not found.
Template "not_found.html.ep" not found.
```

you can create these files in you templates directory

```
/lite_app.pl
/templates/not_found.development.html.ep
/templates/not_found.html.ep
```